# PHP apache document root need to create an alias for url resolution

Tags: php, apache, alias

So I inherited some PHP code.

1. I installed XAMPP on my windows machine
2. I changed the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` paths to

   ```
   C:\dev\CustomCloud\prod
   ```

However, now when I visit `localhost` I see tons of 404 errors

Seems the PHP code is trying to resolve an ALIAS of localhost/matchmaking/

Example:

```
  C:\dev\CustomCloud\prod\assets
```

Is

http://localhost/matchmaking/assets/

What is the best or easiest solution to resolve this as I rarely work with PHP, but I need Apache to serve up this code locally so I can work with the code a bit etc...

Comment: See the apache error log and mention  what you see in log

Answer (score 0):

In your browser url put line https//:localhost if it showing apache home page.Then apache is install successfully on your windows PC ..Then make one file in xammp--> htdocs-->index.php in this file put following code or your folder which you want to run on browser.

```
            <?php
                    echo phpversion();
               ?>
```

Comment: apache is installed correctly .  I commented out default and trying to point at other code someone gave to me to analyze.   problem is the code i got is wanting to have an alias of  "matchmaking"    this stuff is super easy to do in IIS...  so I want to do an alias in apache ...  thx